# Is there a generics equivalent of a sorted TStringList for storing objects?

Tags: delphi, generics

I want to store objects sorted by a name in a list. Duplicates should be ignored and when added the object should automatically be freed. In pre-generics times I would have used a TStringList like this:

```
List := TStringList.Create;
List.Sorted := true;
List.Duplicates := dupIgnore;

List.AddObject('bla', TSomeObject.Create({parameters go here});
List.AddObject('blub', TSomeObject.Create({parameters go here});
List.AddObject('bla', TSomeObject.Create({parameters go here});
```

(Inserting 'bla' twice creates a memory leak, I know, that's one problem I would like to solve here.)

Since Delphi nowadays comes with multiple generic containers, I think there should be one that makes the above cleaner.

The first one I came up with was TDictionary:

```
type
  TSomeObjectContainer = TDictionary<string, TSomeObject>

// etc.
```

Unfortunately TSomeObjectContainer does not allow me to just ignore duplicates, so I have to implement that check myself.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why is being sorted important to you?

Comment: While newer versions of TStringList will handle the freeing of those objects, your example (and probably in general) will lead to a memory leak in combination with dupIgnore. What is the intended behavior when a duplicate is added - which one of the objects shall be kept and which one freed?

Comment: Note that there is a subtle but sometimes important difference between a dicionary and a list: **A list preserves the order in which elements are added, a dictionary does not**. The dictionary is optimized for O(1) read access and sacrifies the element order to achieve this.

Answer (score 5):

If I see what you are looking for, using TDictionary<>.AddOrSetValue() can help with the duplicates. Also the TObjectDictionary class seems to give you a helping hand with memory management.

An example (resulting in no leaks in my tests):

```
  Dict := TObjectDictionary<string, TObject>.Create([doOwnsValues]);
  try
    Dict.AddOrSetValue('c', TObject.Create);
    Dict.AddOrSetValue('c', TObject.Create);
    Dict.AddOrSetValue('d', TObject.Create);
  finally
    Dict.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: The behavior of your approach leads to different results than the stringlist approach. The stringlist will keep the old version of the object while the dictionary will set the new one.

Comment: @Uwe On the plus side, the code here does not leak!!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
TSomeObjectContainer = TDictionary<string, TSomeObject>;
  procedure AddAndFreeDuplicates(aKey: string; aValue: TSomeObject);
end;

procedure TSomeObjectContainer.AddAndFreeDuplicates(aKey: string; aValue: TSomeObject);
begin
  if Self.ContainsKey(aKey) then
    aValue.Free
  else
    Self.Add(aKey, aValue);
end;
```

Then to use it you would do something like this:

```
var
  MyCont: TSomeObjectContainer;
begin
  MyCont := TSomeObjectContainer.Create;
  MyCont.AddAndFreeDuplicates('bla', TSomeObject.Create({parameters go here}));
  MyCont.AddAndFreeDuplicates('blub', TSomeObject.Create({parameters go here}));
  MyCont.AddAndFreeDuplicates('bla', TSomeObject.Create({parameters go here}));
  ...
  MyCont.Free;
end;
```

It depends on how often you add and how many items you have in the list as to whether you should create a list and keep it sorted or not. Ultimately you are going to have to check the duplicates at the point of adding. The question is just how you do that check.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a generic TStringList, unfortunately.  Probably your best bet for a case like this is to build on your original idea: Create a class that inherits from `TDictionary<string, TSomeObject>` and put in your own `Add` method that checks for duplicates and handles them appropriately, or calls `inherited` if there isn't one.

Comment: @TLama: True, but that's a minor concern.  It's necessary to keep a TStringList sorted if you want to check for duplicates *at all*, but the same is not true for a hash table, and it's not difficult to convert the contents of a `TDictionary<TKey, TValue>` into a sorted `TArray<TPair<TKey, TValue>>` if that's needed.

Comment: Mason, sorry. I've deleted my comment before your reply since I realized that sorting might not be necessary requirement (but might be if it was mentioned not only because of checking duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing anything.  The current set of Generic containers does not have the functionality you are looking for.  There is no Generic container that does everything `TStringList` does, so you are going to have to implement some functionality yourself.  If you use `TDictionary`, you will have to implement duplicate checks yourself.  If you use `TList<T>` or `TObjectList<T>`, you will have to implement your own sorting and duplicate checks.